# Na/NaN Error In R

Tags: r

I have just started using R and have a somewhat complex question. So I have a data frame called "data" for which each individual is assigned a PID number. I want to make a loop to find the closest of two dates (SampleDate and LTROT.Date) since there are multiple sample dates for each LTROT.Date. When Running this code I keep getting "Error in start.of.PID:end.of.PID : NA/NaN argument". The data is confidential so I cant provide that. I am new to stackoverflow so I apologize if my questions doesn't meet some of the guidelines.

```
unique <- unique(data$PID)
z <- 1
end.of.PID <- 0
max <- 100000000
sample.ideal <- vector(length = 58)
for(i in unique){
  start.of.PID <- (end.of.PID + 1)
  multi <- sum(unique[i] == data$PID)
  end.of.PID <- (start.of.PID + multi)-1
    for(j in start.of.PID:end.of.PID){
      Sample.Date <- as.Date(data$SampleDate)
      LTROT.Date <- as.Date(data$LTROT.Date)
      time <- Sample.Date[j]-LTROT.Date[j]

      if(time < max){
        max <- time
        sample.ID <- data$SampleID[j]
      }else{
        max <- max
      }

      sample.ideal[z] <- sample.ID
      z <- z + 1
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see few mistake in this code. 1) `unique[i]` should be changed to just `i` in line `multi <- sum(unique[i] == data$PID)`

Answer (score 0):

Mistake in OP's code:

```
unique <- unique(data$PID)
......
for(i in unique){    # i represent as an item in "unique" vector
  start.of.PID <- (end.of.PID + 1)
  multi <- sum(unique[i] == data$PID) #Here i has been used as 'index'

  #The above line should be written as:
  multi <- sum(i == data$PID)
```

Though the sample data is not provided by OP with question but based on logic in `for-loop` it seems a `dplyr` based solution can be an easier option. The result can be received by `self-join` and then filter for the record having minimum date difference. The query can be written as:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% mutate(SampleDate = as.Date(SampleDate),  LTROT.Date = as.Date(LTROT.Date)) %>%
  inner_join(., .,by="PID") %>%
  group_by(PID) %>%
  mutate(MinDateDiff = (SampleDate.x - LTROT.Date.y)) %>%
  filter(MinDateDiff == min(MinDateDiff)) %>%
  select(PID, SampleDate = SampleDate.x, LTROT.Date = LTROT.Date.y, MinDateDiff )
```

Comment: Thanks, @MKR, the dplyr solution does seem to be easier. The current code is throwing an error saying that 'object ID is not found'. if I am trying to select the corresponding SampleID (This is the name of the column), how would I do this?

Comment: @GrantEgnatz There was a type in `select` statement from me. Have a look it should resolve the issue. Even your `for-loop` based solution should have worked now.